# Finding the customer with highest number of orders: group function nested too deeply error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to find the names of the customers with the highest numbers of orders. This is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    cno NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    cname CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR(30) ,
    zip NUMBER,
    phone CHAR(12),
    FOREIGN KEY (zip) REFERENCES zipcodes (zip),
    PRIMARY KEY (cno)
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    ono NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, 
    cno NUMBER NOT NULL,
    eno NUMBER NOT NULL,
    received DATE,
    shipped DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (cno) REFERENCES customers (cno),
    FOREIGN KEY (eno) REFERENCES employee (eno), 
    PRIMARY KEY (ono)
);
```

Here is the code I wrote to return the customers names according to those specifications:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cname
FROM customers, orders
WHERE orders.cno = customers.cno
GROUP BY orders.cno
HAVING COUNT(orders.ono) >= MAX(COUNT(orders.ono));
```

Using this code I get "group function is nested too deeply" as an error. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: Could you include the error number you get, so it is easier for others with the same problem to google your question?

Answer (score 1):

If there may be multiple customers with the highest number of orders the rank or dense rank function would be best e.g.

```
SELECT cname
  FROM (SELECT cname
               rank() OVER (ORDER BY orders DESC) AS order_rank
          FROM (SELECT c.cname,
                       count(o.ono) AS orders
                  FROM customers c
                       LEFT JOIN orders o
                         ON o.cno = c.cno
              GROUP BY c.cname)
 WHERE order_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cant nest group functions (like `MAX` and `COUNT`), so `MAX(COUNT(orders.ono))` would be illegal. You can solve your problem without nesting the function calls by nesting the `SELECT` statements instead:

```
WITH order_count AS  -- This query will do the aggregation and counting.
  SELECT cno, COUNT(cno) count
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY cno
SELECT customers.cname -- This query will find the customer with the highest count.
FROM customers
JOIN order_count ON customers.cno = order_count.cno
WHERE order_count.count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM order_count)
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
SELECT cname FROM ( -- This query picks the top one.
  SELECT customers.cname, ROWNUM rn  -- This query lists the customers ordered by how many orders they have.
  FROM orders
  JOIN customers ON customers.cno = orders.cno
  GROUP BY cno
  ORDER BY COUNT(cno) DESC
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find the names of the customers with the highest numbers of orders.

The fact that you mention customers in plural tells me that you may be interested in more than simply *the customer* with the highest number of orders.  You're not clear on this point, but if you need let's say the 3 customers with the highest number of orders, the following query will do that:

```
with order_cnt_by_customer as (
  select o.cno, count(*) as order_cnt
    from orders o
   group by o.cno
)
select cname
  from (select c.cname,
               row_number() over (order by ocnt.order_cnt desc nulls last) as rn
          from customers c
          left join order_cnt_by_customer ocnt
            on ocnt.cno = c.cno)
 where rn <= 3 -- change this number to get N number of customers
```

If you need a different number of customers, just change the last condition to the number you need.